# How to type math symbols in this forum

Tags: discussion, mathjax

How can I type [math symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) in this forum, like set operators, etc.?

If this question is repeated, I am sorry I just searched and couldn't find an answer.

And could anyone give me hint to use Tags for this question?

Thank you!

Comment: This should be posted on the Mathematics Meta SE

Answer (score 4):

Using Latex and $<\text{the thing you need to type here}>$

E.g. $x^2$ is $\$$x^2$\$$

$\infty$ is $\$$\infty$\$$

$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$ is $\$$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$\$$

Comment: If you use backticks (```), then anything between them appears as unformatted text: `$x^2$`.

Answer (score 1):

<s>First, once you get $5$ reputation, you can ask this on http://meta.stackexchange.com</s> Never mind that, it will only get closed as a duplicate of the MathJax tutorial I will talk about below.

Next, if you want a LaTeX / MathJax tutorial, click [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you are looking for specific symbols like $\pi$ (pi), then you should try [Dextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Hope I helped